# react-select: Prevent long text from overlapping

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-virtualized

I am using [react-select-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-virtualized) component and I modified one of their sandbox examples to include the large text of around 235 characters in the dropdown list.

The modified codesandbox can be accessed from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-williams-ofukf?file=/src/index.jsx)

And it's showing like this:

[image]

How can I fix this? I have a requirement to display large text in the dropdown and wondering if I could improve it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because every option has a long string value and they all wrap and overlap each other. To prevent it, add the below style to change of your option's text wrapping behavior:

```css
.fast-option {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: Edit 66874651/react-select-prevent-long-text-from-overlapping]

Comment: Thanks. That worked and it started showing clearly. One more issue that I can see now is that the width of my drop-down is fixed, so whatever text fits within the length of the drop down window is showing. However, since, there is no horizontal scroll bar option (if I am not wrong), it's not possible to see the whole text. Is it possible to display the remaining text below first line so that everything is visible to the user?

Comment: In case of sandbox example, the window is stretchable to full screen so the whole text is visible but in my code, I have fixed width so that's one more issue I am facing.

Comment: You need to specify the option height explicitly. See [`optionHeight`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select#react-virtualized-select-props), because the virtualized-list needs to know the size of the option to calculate the number of options it should render in a large list. There is no simple way to set the size of the option dynamically unfortunately. @Tan

Comment: Thanks.I specified `optionHeight={60}` and this seems to be increasing the space between the two lines in the dropdown list. However, the text which is not showing is still hidden from the user interface.

Comment: @Tan For some reason `react-select-virtualized` set the `line-height` to a very large number. Try setting `line-height: 30px !important;` and remove `nowrap` to fix your issue

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue. Just curious, any idea what is the `line-height` set by `react-select-virtualized`? I am guessing it's more than `30 px` and hence we limited it to `30 px`.

Comment: @Tan I could be wrong, but it could be set based on the `optionHeight`